# How can I make jQuery dialogs not display on page-load in IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got a page that I'm building for IE8, and it currently has three modal jquery dialogs.   When the page is fully loaded, they're perfectly hidden and invisible to the user until they click the buttons that call the dialogs.  However, when the page first loads, all three of them cluster at the top left corner of the page and then blink away when the page finishes loading.  Here's what it looks like when that happens

[image: When it first loads]

[image: when it finishes loading]

It loads just fine in Firefox, but that's not what my users are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting display:none as a default CSS style on the dialog div